# Bootstrap - Fixed navbar doesn't do what's expected?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I created a navbar with the list:
Active a.k.a. name of the site a.k.a. AnimuTuga;

Anime

Manga

Jogos

Opinião

Outros (dropdown-menu with: AMV, Cosplay, Passatempos)

Sobre

Contacto

The thing is:
-The "Opinião" button doesn't appear, I don't know why...
-I want to put the dropdown-menu a.k.a. "Outros" with th same distance as the others on the left like Anime and Manga and put Sobre and Contacto on the right.

This is for bootstrap.

Here is the HTML and CSS.

**HTML**

```
!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">
  
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AnimuTuga</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="Anime"><a href="#Anime">Anime</a></li>
          <li class="Manga"><a href="#manga">Manga</a></li>
          <li class="Jogos"><a href="#Jogos">Jogos</a></li>
          <li class="Opinião"><a href="#Opinião"></a></li>
          <li class="Outros">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Outros <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">AMV</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Cosplay</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Passatempos</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li><li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
          
  
  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Sticky footer with fixed navbar</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS. A fixed navbar has been added within <code>#wrap</code> with <code>padding-top: 60px;</code> on the <code>.container</code>.</p>
    <p>Back to <a href="../sticky-footer">the default sticky footer</a> minus the navbar.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted credit">Example courtesy <a href="http://martinbean.co.uk">Martin Bean</a> and <a href="http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/">Ryan Fait</a>.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


            <div id="push"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Not required for template or sticky footer method. */

#wrap > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}
.container .credit {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#footer > .container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try improve your code:

```
<li class="Opinião"><a href="#Opinião"></a></li>
```

to:

```
<li class="Opiniao"><a href="#Opiniao">Opinião</a></li>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bo8vjssm/1/)

[Explanation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/syndata.html#characters), why name of your class has to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you know how I put the "Sobre" and "Contacto" more to the right? I don't know how to refer them in css :/